# Phonegap app - localStorage on iOS (Clarification needed)

Tags: javascript, ios, cordova, local-storage, phonegap

I am building a hybrid app using PhoneGap. It needs to work on iOS. I am a little confused and hope someone could help.

I am using localStorage with my navigation. 
My app has different chapters and i am reusing the UI.

```
<a href="chapter.html" data-ajax="false" onClick="localStorage.setItem('chapter', '1')" class="ui-btn">Chapter 1</a>
```

When you click on the url, it gets the chapter from localStorage and know which content to get.

```
var chapter = localStorage.getItem('chapter');
```

**My requirements**
localStorage only needs to be persistent as long as the user, is using the app. 

It's OK, if localStorage is lost when the use closes the app.

But when he is using the app, he should have access to localStorage. To get the correct content, you need the chapter nr which you get from localStorage.

**What i am confused about.** 

On the cordava site, it states this.
iOS stores localStorage data in a location that may be cleaned out by the OS when space is required.

**My Question**

Could this possible happen, when the user is still using the app?
I don't want him to be in the middle of navigating to a new page, and getting incorrect data because localStorage was lost.

Would it be better to use sessionStorage instead?

All I really want to do, is send the chapter nr to the new page, so i could fetch the correct content. (send information to new page)

Is using localStorage and sessionStorage the correct way to do this?

If there is a better way, please let me know.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [cordova-plugin-nativestorage](https://github.com/TheCocoaProject/cordova-plugin-nativestorage). ([npm link](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-nativestorage))

In the [storage page](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/cordova/storage/storage.html) that you have referred they have specified to use other plugins as the `LocalStorage` is **non-persistent**. Also **none** of the other methods mentioned there like [`WebSQL`](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/cordova/storage/storage.html#websql), [`IndexedDB`](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/cordova/storage/storage.html#indexeddb) suit your requirements.

This plugin uses `SharedPreferences` in Android and `NSUserDefaults` in iOS. So the values of the variables stored are persistent until the app is uninstalled. :)

That is why, the developers claim that, this plugin was developed. Take a look at the reasons [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-nativestorage#why).

Also see [when](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-nativestorage#when-to-use-the-plugin) to use and [when](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-nativestorage#when-not-to-use-the-plugin) not to use the plugin.

Answer (score 0):

At the moment (March 2019) cordova-plugin-nativestorage hasn't been updated in 8 months, so I ended up going with [cordova-sqlite-storage](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-sqlite-storage). This is another reliable cross-platform option and currently the most active.

To answer your question about occurrence, I believe this could happen while the user is using the application as it is iOS clearing the data independently of any user behavior, but I have not been able to confirm this yet.

I may have stumbled over a way to prevent iOS from clearing the localstorage [at the bottom of this post](https://marco.org/2011/10/13/ios5-caches-cleaning). Not sure if I would be comfortable relying on this feature for data permanence still trying to track that down, comments very welcome on that.